# C code passing struct into function Stack overflow

Tags: c, function, struct, stack-overflow

Okay so I'm having an issue with a current assignment (trust me this is a minuscule part of it) as we are required to write in C code and not C++, and we are not allowed to change certain parts of code. So I have a struct defined:

```
    typedef struct someStruct {
    int what;
    int something[MAX];
    int another[MAX];
} someType;
```

in main() I initialize all the values in a defined struct:

```
someType whatever, *whatptr;
```

EDIT:of course set the pointer to the struct, trying to simplify the code for the example It is present in my code already

```
whatptr = &whatever;
whatever.what = 0;
// initialize both arrays to hold 0 at all indexes
// Then I must call a function progRun()
progRun();  //I need to pass struct 'whatever' in some way
```

Now progRun() looks like this:

```
void progRun(){
printWhat(&whatever);

    if (whatever.what == 0) {
    //do stuff 
    }
}
```

I can't change anything inside this code except what parameters to pass inside the progRun() function and I can add stuff before printWhat(). I've tried changing progRun to

```
void progRun(someType *stptr)
```

then calling it in main as

```
progRun(whatptr);
```

but this causes a stack overflow issue for some reason, I've tried stepping through with a debugger and it only occurs when the function is called. Is there a better way to pass the 'whatever' struct to the function so it can be passed into progRun() and printWhat() and can access 'whatever.what'?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! in the meantime I'll try to figure it myself if I can.

EDIT: Something else must be wrong in the code even though everything else has compiled and ran perfectly fine until this code was added. If I can break down the code and find out what's wrong I'll update the question. And no I cannot post the whole code as it is an assignment (this isn't the goal of the assignment trust me it focuses on data forwarding and more, just need to get this basic thing working) Thank you for help everyone.

EDIT: the MAX number used in the struct for something[MAX] and another[MAX] was extremely large ( I left my desktop that I started this project with back home, I'm currently using an old laptop that can't handle large arrays). All the answers below, and some of the stuff I used before now works fine.

Comment: Please post a minimal working code example demonstrating a problem.

Comment: Are you sure it's a stack overflow and not a different type of crash?

Comment: Here is the error: "Unhandled exception at 0x004123f7 in program.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow", it occurs when progRun() function is called.

Comment: @Doug doesn't compiler tell you the exact line where the overflow is caused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void progRun(someStruct *ptr) {
    someStruct whatever2 = *ptr;
    printWhat(whatever2);
    if (whatever2.what == 0) { ...
}

whatptr = &whatever;
progRun(whatptr);
```

Your problem was that:

- you need to pass a pointer to `whatever`, yet you were passing a variable (`whatptr`) that had absolutely nothing to do with `whatever`.

  You need to first assign the pointer to whatever into your pointer variable.
- You are not dereferencing the pointer in the function

Alternately, get rid of pointer variables:

```
void progRun(someType *stptr) {
    printWhat(*stptr);
    if (stptr->what == 0) { ...
}

progRun(&whatever);
```

Comment: I forgot to include whatptr = &whatever; in my example but that is what I did before. this is exactly where I run into the issue, it crashes after the progRun() call

Comment: Thanks for your response, but as I stated I cannot change the pointer variables. printWhat must remain printWhat(&whatever) and the if statement must remain if(whatever.what). I'd prefer doing it your way because that's how I've done it in the past. Is there a way to set the pointer back to a struct?

Comment: @Doug - see the second line of the answer. `SomeStruct whatever2 = *stptr;`

Comment: @DVK yes just noticed that I actually tried that already, but if you stated that too there must be something else wrong with the code. I wish I could post my full code but we cannot post the assignment online for obvious reasons. It stinks this is a just a tiny part of it too but looks like I'm on my own. I believe you would have the correct answer first in this case so I'll accept it. Much thanks though.

Comment: @Doug - try to take existing code and trim down to the smallest possible runnable subset. We'll take a look

Comment: @DVK After breaking the code down I realized it would crash only when stptr was called inside progRun(). The function calls are correct but the professor had defined two huge arrays that are stored in the struct. The #DEFINE MAX number, that is used twice in the struct definition is more than I'm guessing this older laptop I'm using atm can handle. We're not supposed to change that either but he'll have to understand in this case. I would have messed around with the function call forever without your help thank you. Well time to get started on the real meat of this assignment haha.

Answer (score 0):

Instruction

```
someType whatever, *whatptr;
```

is the problem:

`*whatptr` will not point to the `struct` `whatever` unless you do the assignment as follows:

```
whatptr = &whatever;
```

Alternatively you could dynamically allocate memory on the heap for a pointer to your `struct` `whatever` by using the `malloc()` function and pass the pointer returned by malloc to the function `progrun`:

```
whatptr = (someType*) malloc ( sizeof(someType) );
if (whatptr == NULL) exit (1);

//whatever you need to do with your code

progrun(whatptr); // call function like this
```

In this case of course you will need to dereference your pointer to access member elements of the `struct` by using the arrow `->` operator:

```
whatpr->what = 0; // for example
```

Also, check these tutorials to understand both approaches:

- [link 1](http://www.taranets.net/cgi/ts/1.37/ts.ws.pl?w=329;b=282)
- [link 2](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~heap/270F02/node31.html)

---

If you can't change `print` and `if` statements then you should pass your function a copy of your `struct`:

```
void progRun( someType whatever ){ // <---Passing by copy
printWhat(&whatever);

    if (whatever.what == 0) {
    //do stuff 
    }
}
```

and in your `main()` you should just call the function like this:

```
someType whatever;
//assign values to members of the struct
progRun(whatever);
```

and do not need at all to define and assign a pointer to the `struct`.

Though passing variables to functions by copy (especially when they are objects composed by many variables such as a `struct` is) is not a good behaviour:

- it will require an overhead to copy all member elements
- your copy will have a limited scope, which means that any change you do to the variable inside of the function will be lost when your function ends and will not be reflected on variable at main scope

Comment: You don't need to dynamically allocate memory for a **struct**, only for a pointer to one. Since he has a struct, he doesn't need that.

Comment: @DVK yeah, a typing mistake..thks!

Comment: @Matteo My bad in typing up the example, this is already included in my code. The main issue is how to pass it into the function without changing print and if statement inside.

Comment: @Doug try passing the struct by copy, at least to debug, it will lwt you understand if the problem is in the print function or somewhere else.

Comment: @Matteo I've tried this too there must be another issue in my code. It compiles with no errors. I believe you would be correct in the regular circumstance. I've tried all methods mentioned so far and stepped through the code with the debugger. The error occurs when the progRun() is called before it steps into the actual code. That's why I thought it was how I was pssing the struct into the code. I removed the print function and received the same error.

Comment: @Doug I'm sorry I couldn't help more!

Comment: @Matteo You and DVK helped me a ton, I realized the function call and how I was passing the struct was not wrong. See my edit for what went wrong, quite lame after all that work ha.